# Removing tangential perspective distortion with OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to measure a real-world 3D object from a photo. I have the object's real-world height and am trying to calculate it's width from the photo. However, there is tangential distortion in the photo. Is there a way to use OpenCV to undistort the photo. The camera was resting on the ground at a 145 degree angle (pointing upwards at the object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you attempting to write an application that can do it for various objects in various photos? Or just the one specifically?

If you want to do it for various objects you will need more information about your camera's lens by capturing a calibration image. (See website below). If you only have the one image, then you don't have enough information to cancel the distortion due to the lens.

See [this](https://hackaday.io/project/12384-autofan-automated-control-of-air-flow/log/41862-correcting-for-lens-distortions) website for typical lens distortion correction techniques.

Comment: Thanks, Hein. I would like to automatically do this with an app. The link doesn’t mention anything about the camera angle. Where does that come into play?

Comment: As a matter of fact, me and a friend have thought of building such an app ourselves. It is a harder problem to solve than you might think. But I will still try to help where I can.

It all depends on how you use the calibration. It seems that the method the website uses is to image the checkerboard at a known camera angle (namely zero). Then you can calculate the 'obj_points'. See the mentioned file, or google "opencv calibrate camera" and look at the top result.

There are more complex ways where you don't have to line it up perfectly, and then need more images.